# Jenkins - Publish Over CIFS Plugin

Tags: plugins, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am getting confused with this plug in.

Basically my target is to Deploy files from Server1 to Server2

Now the `buildoutput` dir is in a specific location in Server1

example: `E:\BuildOutput\Apps\Application1\Bin\Release\`

I need to deploy them in Server2: `C:\Program Files\Tools\Application1\Bin\`

How do I set up this plugin to work to what I need?

I am getting stressed in the amount of files that needs to be deployed to another server, I just wished a simple xcopy tool to another server could work.

I am looking for plugin if not this, to basically deploy only the files that has been changed to another server for automated feature testing.

Any methods will do too, that's if possible.

Comment: I suppose you did look through the plug-in page and provided details. What is the actual problem? Did it return some error? CIFS plugin copies files from a Workspace to some Share. Please note: "Source... Path is constructed from workspace root." Make sure files are in your workspace, folders are specified correctly and you are ready to go.

Comment: yes i did, like i said in my example the workspace is different from the buildoutput path and is deployed to server 2 on different path.

i did tried, there are no errors but no files were transferred, also i am concern about only specific files can be transferred, i am not sure how this will work on 300 files(with different extensions) to be deployed. 

i prefer if there's other method than this, or if i could make xcopy work that would be perfect.

Answer (score 6):

XCOPY should work fine.  You need to create a share on Server2 in the desired location
Go to the Jenkins configuration and click "Add build step"->"Execute Windows batch command"
You should be able to execute any DOS commands you need there.

```
XCOPY E:\BuildOutput\Apps\Application1\Bin\Release\my_app.exe \\SERVER2\Share
```

If you don't want to share your applications bin directory:

1. Make a different share on Server2
2. Configured build to XCOPY to the new share
3. Add Server2 as a build node (Manage Jenkins->Nodes)
4. Create a new build job to move the files where you want them
5. Tie the new job to Server2 build node (Check the box "Restrict where this project can be run" in the job config

Answer (score 3):

If your account has admin rights on Server2 you can just connect to the admin share of the C: drive like this:

```
XCOPY E:\BuildOutput\Apps\Application1\Bin\Release\* \\SERVER2\c$\Program Files\Tools\Application1\Bin\
```